# What is the best way to set react-hook-form defaultValues in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

I have a statically generated Next.js site with frontend only. I have a page `pages/feedback/[id]/edit.tsx`. Getting this dynamic id in a nested `FeedbackForm` component & setting `defaultValues` like so:

```js
export const FeedbackForm = ({ editing }: { editing: boolean }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query
  const feedbackData = getFeedback(id as string)

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      title: editing ? feedbackData.title : '',
      category: editing ? feedbackData.category : categories[0], // an array from local json file
      status: editing ? feedbackData.status : statusList[0], // an array from local json file
      description: editing ? feedbackData.description : '',
    }
  })

  // ...
}
```

The problem is that, initially, the `id` from `router.query` is `undefined`. As I've read in Next.js docs, client side router will take over after hydration and `id` will be filled with the value. This means that `FeedbackForm` component renders twice and, initially, `getFeedbackData` returns `undefined` (because `undefined` id was passed as an argument).

So my question is, what is the best way to set `defaultValues` in this case? Should I even use `defaultValues` here?

- Should I modify `getFeedbackData` function to return object with empty string values if `undefined` was passed in?
- Should I subscribe to the `router` object changes and only then fill the form with default values? I saw this being done with `reset` function in `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you use Next.JS from the tags.

Using `useEffect` and `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` can be the solutions.

It depends on what you want to achieve.

If you need SEO, for instance, use `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`. If you need a lot of dynamic data on your page, it's more scalable to render your page at run time (SSR), and therefore `getServerSideProps` would be the preferred method. (just keep in mind that the SEO is not the only reason why you would choose one over another)

Otherwise, `useEffect` will be enough for your needs.

The following codes are just examples, but you'll get the ideas.

1. using `useEffect`

```
interface FeedbackFormProps {
  editing: boolean;
}

type FeedbackData = {
  title: string;
  category: string;
  status: string;
  description: string;
};

const FeedbackForm: React.FC<FeedbackFormProps> = ({ editing }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [feedbackData, setFeedbackData] = useState<FeedbackData | null>(null);
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      title: editing && feedbackData?.title ? feedbackData.title : '' ,
      category: editing && feedbackData?.category ? feedbackData?.category : categories[0], // an array from local json file
      ...
    }
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const { id } = router.query;

    const fetchFeedback = async () => {
      const result = await getFeedback(id as string);
      setFeedbackData(result);
    };

    fetchFeedback();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  if (!feedbackData) return <div>{/* loading spinner etc. */}</div>;

  return <div>{/* do something with data */}</div>;
};

export default FeedbackForm;
```

2. using `getServerSideProps`

```
interface FeedbackFormProps {
  feedbackData: FeedbackData;
  editing: boolean;
}

type FeedbackData = {
  title: string;
  category: string;
  status: string;
  description: string;
};

const FeedbackForm: React.FC<FeedbackFormProps> = ({editing, feedbackData}) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      title: editing && feedbackData?.title ? feedbackData.title : '' ,
      category: editing && feedbackData?.category ? feedbackData?.category : categories[0], // an array from local json file
      ...
    }
  })

  /* you can use setState to save the feedbackData and use it for later */
  /* because if it's not editing mode, you might have to refetch the data */

  if (!feedbackData) return <div>{/* loading spinner etc. */}</div>;

  return <div>{/* do something with data */}</div>;
};

export default FeedbackForm;

export const getServerSideProps = async (context: NextPageContext) => {
  const { id } = context.query;
  const feedbackData = await getFeedback(id as string);

  return {
    props: {
      feedbackData: feedbackData,
    },
  };
};
```

TMI: I assume the editing mode is able to toggle, so it might be better to save data using `useState` even in the case of #2 too.

In conclusion, since the `editing` prop from the parent mainly decides the default value, I recommend using `useEffect`